# Show that $(-1)^{n}\sqrt[n]{n}\sin(\frac{1}{n})=\tfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\tfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)$

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

> I would like to show that :
>   $$(-1)^{n}\sqrt[n]{n}\sin(\frac{1}{n})=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)$$
>   by starting from the left side and get the right side :

My Proof:

> Note that :
>   $$\sin(x)=x+\mathcal{O}(x^{3})$$
>   $$e^{x}=1+\mathcal{O}(x)$$

\begin{align*}
(-1)^{n}\sqrt[n]{n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)&= (-1)^{n}e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(n\right)}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&=  (-1)^{n}\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n} \right) \right)\left(\dfrac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{3}}\right) \right)\\
&=  (-1)^{n}\left[\dfrac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{3}}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{4}} \right)  \right]\\
&=(-1)^{n}\left[\dfrac{1}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}}\right) \right]\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)\\
\end{align*}

since : $\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3}} \right)+\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{4}}\right)=\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)$

- $$\frac{\dfrac{1}{n^3}}{\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^2}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0 \implies \dfrac{1}{n^{3}}=\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right) $$
- $$\frac{\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^4}}{\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0 \implies \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{4}}=\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^{2}} \right)$$
- Is my proof correct  ?

Comment: looks ok to me!

Comment: It should be $n^4$ in the last denominator of the third line; and indeed only the $\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^2} \right) $ remains as $\frac{1}{n^3} = \mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^2} \right) $. (Since $\frac{\dfrac{1}{n^3}}{\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^2}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, for instance)

Comment: Comment after the edit: this is correct, but you only want/need $\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{\ln(n)}{n^2} \right)$, not $\mathcal{O}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^2} \right)$, in both bullets in the end. (This is actually what the bullets prove, and even though the other, slightly stronger statement is also true, that is not necessary.)

Comment: i edit my post thank you